# Как задать значение кошелька?

Tags: python, discord, sqlite3, discord.py, discord-api

Вот код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import sqlite3

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'c-')
bot.remove_command('help')

connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        rep INT,
        lvl INT 
        )""")

    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', '{member.id}', 0, 0, 1)")
            else:
                pass

    connection.commit()
    print('BOT HAS CONNECTED')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', '{member.id}', 0, 0, 1)")
        connection.commit()
    else:
        pass

#Commands

@bot.command(aliases = ['cash'])
async def balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()} :moneybag:***"""
            ))
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{member}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()} :moneybag:***"""
            ))

bot.run(Токен палить не буду')
```

вот я пишу команду
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и он мне пишет None
то есть как сделать так чтобы там отображалась цифра?

Сразу говорю если сделать вот так `await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed( description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :moneybag:***""" )) то есть добавил после`    `fetchone`   `[0]`

Answer (score -1):

Будет лучше вывести запрос к БД и ответ БД в отдельную переменную, чтобы не получить по итогу говнокод.

```
@bot.command(aliases=['cash'])
async def balance(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author

    cursor.execute(f'SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id={member.id}')
    balance = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f'Баланс пользователя **{str(member)}** составляет {int(balance)} :moneybag:"))
```

Comment: Он мне пишет то что где `balance = cursor.fetchone()[0]` там ошибка, а в консоли пишет `SyntaxError = invalid syntax`

Comment: А нет, это просто малейшие ошибки

Comment: Не всё равно не работает

Comment: Это я так понял из-за того что мы int пытаемся использовать в None

Comment: @Gan5terone2008 извини, исправил ошибку в коде, пропустил `)`

Comment: окей) Прощаю)))

Comment: Не он прост всё равно не работает